# how to adding index on Map fields in entity using object db

Tags: java, jpa, objectdb

i want to add index in  map attribute  i doen't have any idea about adding index in map attribute

i have refer objectdb site link but i doesn't find soultion    @index is enough for added index

for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Customer.TABLE_NAME)
public class Country {

    @index
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = Country.TABLE_TRANSLATION_NAME,
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Country.TABLE_NAME),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = NameTranslation.TABLE_NAME))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = Language.TABLE_NAME)
    private Map<Language, NameTranslation> names;

}
```

language  and nametranslation has seperate entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this forum thread](http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/682) on ObjectDB website regarding indexing map keys, and [this forum thread](http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/600) about indexing map values.

You can set an index on keys using the [@Key(index="true")](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jdo/annotations/Key) annotation, and on values using the [@Value(index="true")](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jdo/annotations/Value) annotation, but as explained above, an index on keys will not be useful in queries in the current ObjectDB version (2.5.7).

Comment: what should i do for map attribute adding index   ?@Key(index="true")  just like befor  e attribute or any thing else i need to add

Comment: Don't use @Key(index="true"). Please read the referenced forum threads in the answer. Index on map keys are currently not supported. See the workaround in the forum post.